# Xcode and Swift: change order of suggestion when coding

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm new to the Swift language and using Xcode too.

How could we change the order of the code suggestion when programming?

For example, when I type `int`, Xcode is giving me these suggestions:

> intmax_t
>   Int
>   internal
>   ...

I think it could be a good advantage to have `Int` like first suggestion. Is there a way to have this issue fixed?

I tried typing a bunch of time `int` and select the "Int" option, just to see if Xcode orders the suggestion by the most used, but it keeps giving me the same.

Comment: I don't think you have much control over the suggestions but you should probably get into the habit of using the correct case since Swift is case sensitive. It will improve the suggestions you get.